# Dynamic allocation example in C

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation, function-declaration

What is going on with adress and pointer types.
Can we dealocate the momory in the main function.

```
int *read(int *n) {
  int i, *niz;
  do { 
    printf("n="); 
    scanf("%d", n);
  } while (*n < 1);
  
  niz = (int *)malloc(*n * sizeof(int));
  
  for (i = 0; i < *n; i++) { 
    printf("%d. broj: ", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", niz + i); 
  }

  return niz;
}

int main() {
  int i, n, *niz;
  niz = read(&n); 
  printf("Niz:");
  
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf(" %d", niz[i]);
  
  free(niz);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is legal to call `free` from `main()`. What problem are you having?

Comment: Sevo, Aside: `niz = (int *)malloc(*n * sizeof(int));` better as `niz = malloc(sizeof niz[0] * *n);`.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

Comment: I don't understand why do we need a function pointer (*read), and why do we need the pointer in the read function while using n?

Comment: *read isn't a function pointer, it is a function returning a pointer to an integer.

Comment: You need to check the value returned by the function, as well as the value it scans. Always check that `scanf` returns the number of items you expect to be scanned, in this case `1`.

Comment: If we're being thorough, the return of `malloc` probably should have been checked before attempting to use it.

Comment: `read` is the name of a library function.  Better to use a different name to avoid confusion.

Answer (score -1):

> I don't understand why do we need a function pointer (*read), and why
> do we need the pointer in the read function while using n?

To make it clear you may rewrite the function declaration

```
int *read(int *n) {
```

the following way

```
int * ( read(int *n) ){
```

That is it is a function that has one parameter with the name `n` of the type `int *` and the return type  `int *`.

In main the variable `n` declared like

```
int i, n, *niz;
```

is passed to the function `read` by reference through a pointer to it

```
niz = read(&n);
```

because we want that the variable would get a value assigned in the function. So dereferencing the pointer the function will have a direct access to the original variable `n` declared in main and can change its value.

This value assigned in the function read to the original variable `n` declared in main through a pointer to it is used in main in this for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  printf(" %d", niz[i]);
```

Otherwise if the function would be declared like

```
int * ( read(int n) ){
```

and called like

```
niz = read(n);
```

then the function would deal with a copy of the value of the variable `n` declared in main. Changing the copy of the value of the variable `n` within the function leaves the value of the original variable `n` declared in main unchanged. It is the copy of the value that would be changed not the original variable itself.

Pay attention to that the returned pointer from the function points to a dynamically allocated memory. So using the pointer in main you can free the allocated memory within the function.